# Bazel - gtkmm library - missing dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, bazel, gtkmm

I have created a Bazel project (C++) and have tried to include the gtkmm library in my project.

I get the below error, that header files are missing, e.g.:

```
Showing Recent Messages
../mediapipe/external/gtkmm/gtkmm/accelerator.cc:18:10: fatal error: 'glibmm/utility.h' file not found
#include <glibmm/utility.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Error in child process '/usr/bin/xcrun'. 1
Aspect @tulsi//:tulsi/tulsi_aspects.bzl%tulsi_outputs_aspect of //mediapipe/examples/motionize/motionize:motionize up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/mediapipe/examples/motionize/motionize/motionize.tulsiouts
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_{user}/5a416b3c18d355cbf1dfbcf0102ffc0b/external/gtkmm/BUILD.bazel:7:11: Compiling gtkmm/accelerator.cc failed: (Aborted): wrapped_clang_pp failed: error executing command 
Elapsed time: 10.459s, Critical Path: 0.45s
12 processes: 12 internal.
<*> Running Bazel completed in 10826.492 ms
Build did NOT complete successfully
```

The includes in the library do not seem to find the header files in general, not just this one. I have tried different setups and also a local repository instead of http_archive and I still get this kind of errors

Note: I am using Tulsi to create the Bazel xcode project

I have added the following in my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
http_archive(
    name = "gtkmm",
    strip_prefix = "gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk",
    urls = ["https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.zip"],
    build_file = "@//third_party:gtkmm.BUILD",
)
```

I also added the `gtkmm.BUILD` file which looks like this:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

licenses(["notice"])  # BSD license

exports_files(["LICENSE"])

cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**/*.cc"],
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "*.h",
        "gtkmm/**/object_p.h",
        "**/*.hg",
        "**/*.h",
        "**/selectiondata_private.h"
    ]),
    includes = glob([
        "*.h",
        "gtkmm/**/object_p.h",
        "**/*.hg",
        "**/*.h",
        "**/selectiondata_private.h"

    ]),
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Finally my `BUILD` file:

```
cc_binary(
    name="motionize",
    srcs=["main.cpp"],
    copts = [
        "-Iexternal/gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk/gtkmm",
        "-Iexternal/gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk/",
        "-Iexternal/gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk/src",
        "-Iexternal/gtkmm-4.8.0/gtk/gtkmm/private",
        ],
    deps=[
        "//mediapipe/framework:calculator_framework",
        "//mediapipe/calculators/core:pass_through_calculator",
        "//mediapipe/calculators/image:image_cropping_calculator",
        "//mediapipe/calculators/image:scale_image_calculator",
        "//mediapipe/framework/formats:image_frame",
        "//mediapipe/framework/formats:image_frame_opencv",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:opencv_core",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:opencv_highgui",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:opencv_imgproc",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:opencv_imgcodecs",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:opencv_video",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:parse_text_proto",
        "//mediapipe/framework/port:status",
        "@gtkmm//:main",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the entire project in xcode once?